# Create external partition table in SQL Serverless

Tags: t-sql, serverless, azure-synapse

I was trying to find a script to create partition external tables in Serverless SQL pool in azure synapse

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
      [col1] varchar(8000),
      [col2] varchar(3000),
      [month] int
)

WITH (
    LOCATION = 'myLocation/TaxiData/',
    DATA_SOURCE = population_ds,  
    FILE_FORMAT = census_file_format,
    PARTITION = [Month]
)
```

but it is not working. Is it possible? I always find documentaction regarding dedicated SQL pool but I want to know if I can do it in serverless as well.

Comment: It's meaningless to create a local partition for an **external** table. What are you expecting to happen, exactly?

Comment: ...and [_none_ of the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` variations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql) (for SQL Server, Azure SQL, Managed Instance, Synapse, and PDW) have a `PARTITION` option. The `PARTITION` option is only valid for non-external `CREATE TABLE` commands.

Comment: (Though the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT` command does create a table, the documentation's Remarks section [states that it is always a non-partitioned table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-as-select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#GeneralRemarks)).

Answer (score 2):

You can’t create partitioned external tables directly in Synapse Serverless. You can create a View and use the filepath function to add partition columns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/create-use-views#partitioned-views

Alternatively if you create partitioned tables in a Synapse Lake Database using spark then this is queryable in Synapse Serverless